# How to access vector class array methods in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stdvector, icc

```
class Bird{

public:
    void init();
    Bird();//constructor
    void foo();//its defined somewhere
};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::vector <Bird> B[51];

    for (int i = 0; i < 51; i++)
       B[i].foo();
}
```

it seems vector is a safe and modern way to generate 51 object safely.

assume Im creating an Object Array from class Bird. and want to use each objects method. (I cant use static object array because I have to swap the array members later.)

(and I didnt use C++ since 2000. Now I have to)

Comment: You have an array of vectors. It looks like you want a single vector.

Comment: vector seems modern way of using dynamic array in C++. and I want it to use. so you have an solution instead of unrate question ?

Comment: Using `[]` you have created an array of 51 vectors. To have a vector with 51  elements you use `std::vector <Bird> B(51);`

Comment: I'll just point out that `std::vector` was around for about 15 years, even longer if you count the original STL implementation... So "modern" is maybe not the word I'd choose.

Comment: Thanks Mr Bo. I saw my bad. I didnt know to use ( instead of [. that solves problem

Comment: @N.Ramos See [`std::vector`s constructor reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) and [facepalm](http://i0.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/facebook/000/000/554/facepalm.jpg) :P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as mr Boo response exactly.

```
class Bird{

public:
    void init();
    Bird();//constructor
    void foo();//its defined somewhere
};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::vector <Bird> B(51); // fixed line

    for (int i = 0; i < 51; i++)
       B[i].foo();
}
```